# Meteor : Internal server error [500] with Meteor.methods()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have the collection "menu" with structure:

```
{
"_id" : "vJQr7EuieDHMuX2nx" "section" : "vine" "price" : "200" "category" : "bar"
"_id" : "vJQr7EuieDHMuX4rf" "section" : "beer" "price" : "200" "category" : "kitchen"
"_id" : "vJQr7EuieDHMuX5tg" "section" : "milk" "price" : "200" "category" : "kbar"
"_id" : "vJQr7EuieDHMuX4sc" "section" : "beer" "price" : "200" "category" : "kitchen"
"_id" : "vJQr7EuieDHMuX2xs" "section" : "vine" "price" : "200" "category" : "bar"
}
```

I want to show the user only "section" without repeating
For this I used 
Menu.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$section"}}]) 
but it's not working
How can I do this? May be to use a different method?

Server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getSections': function () {
    var pipeline = [{$group:{_id:"$section"}}];
    var result = Menu.aggregate(pipeline);
    var sections = [];
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      sections.push(result[i]._id);
    };
    console.log(sections);
    return sections;
  }
});
```

result in the server: [ 'vine', 'beer', 'milk' ]

Client side:

```
 Template.MobBarMenu.helpers({
        'list': function(){
            this.render('MobBarMenu', {});
        },
        'listSections': function () {
           Meteor.call('getSections', function (err, data) {
               console.log(data);
               // return data;
           });
        }
    });

template name="MobBarMenu"
            {{#each listSections}}
                {{this}}
            {{/each}}
template
```

I don't know where to find the solution

Comment: Your server console should have an error message that points to the actual error. You can also use `meteor debug` to debug your server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an advanced publication. On your template code, add a named collection (only on client). Then you can create a helper to get the data and subscribe to the publication.

```
const Sections = new Mongo.Collection('sections');
Template.Menu.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe('sections')
})
Template.Menu.helpers({
  sections() {
    return Sections.find();
  }
});
```

Then, create a publication that writes to this.

```
Meteor.publish('sections', function () {
  const handle = Menu.find({}, {
    fields: {
      _id: 0
      section: 1
   }
  }).observe({
    added: doc => this.added('sections', doc.section, doc),
    changed: doc => this.changed('sections', doc.section, doc),
    removed: doc => this.removed('sections', doc.section, doc)
  });
  this.ready();
  this.onStop(() => handle.stop())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses MiniMongo - it's own wrapper of nodejs MongoDB driver.

And by default collecions has no method `aggregate`. You can find it in a few packages, like [monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation](https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation).

Or (which better imo) you can get access to raw collection with native to Meteor [`rawCollection`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) method:

```js
Menu.rawCollection().aggregate(pipeline, function(err, res) {
    //do stuff here
})
```